# relation between measure and integral for all $\epsilon >0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in L(X,F,\mu)$ integrable function. Show that $\forall \epsilon >0$ we have

$\mu(x\in X / \mid f(x)\mid > \epsilon)\leq \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\int_X \mid f\mid d\mu$

I've done this:

Let $E=\{x\in X/\mid f(x)\mid >\epsilon\}$, then we have that $(\epsilon. \textit{X}_E) < \mid f(x)\mid$, $\forall x\in X$, where $\textit{X}_E$ denotes the characteristic function on E.

As both of the functions are positive measurables, we can take the integral in both sides, so
$\int_X \epsilon\textit{X}_E d\mu <\int \mid f\mid d\mu$, then $\epsilon .\mu(E)<\int_X \mid f\mid d\mu$, and we have the result.

I want to know if I'm right or if I'm missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and the result is known as [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality).

Note that $f$ need not be integrable since the right hand side is always well-defined as the integral of a nonnegative function. In this case, both sides of the inequality might be $+\infty$ which would mean that the strict inequalities $<$ in your proof would need to be loose $\le$.

Comment: But now with that observation I figure that if the function is integrable, the left side can take the $+\infty$ value, while the right side cannot, so, the inequality would failed in that case, right?

Comment: The proof of the inequality precisely shows that the left hand side is finite if the right hand side is.

If the right hand side is infinite, then the left hand side need not be finite, and might also be infinite (except if you add the condition that the measure $\mu$ is finite for example).